# Как в питоне не прописывать много условий if

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Написал скрипт перебора всех значений клавиатуры по порядку, но после реализации этого скрипта столкнулся с проблемой того, что при оптимизации кода не знаю, как заменить большое кол-во условий `if`.

```
# 48 - 57 цифры
# 97 - 122 En буквы 
mas_pas = [] # массив En буквы 
for x in range(97, 123):
    mas_pas.append(chr(x))
for x in range(48, 58):
    mas_pas.append(chr(x))        
# 48 - 57 цифры
# 97 - 122 En буквы 
mas_pas = [] # массив En буквы 
for x in range(97, 123): # тут заполняем массив буквами 
    mas_pas.append(chr(x))
for x in range(48, 58): # тоже заполняем массив, но цифрами
    mas_pas.append(chr(x))


mas = [] # массив всех значений
zamena = [] # тут идут индексы элементов значений
for x in range(6): 
    mas.append("a") 
    zamena.append(0) # 


    while True:
        zamena[0] += 1 
        if zamena[0] > 35:
            zamena[0] = 0
            zamena[1] += 1
        if zamena[1] > 35:
            zamena[1] = 0
            zamena[2] += 1
        if zamena[2] > 35:
            zamena[2] = 0
            zamena[3] += 1
        if zamena[3] > 35:
            zamena[3] = 0
            zamena[4] += 1
        if zamena[4] > 35:
            zamena[4]  = 0
    
        for x in range(0,5): 
            mas[x] = mas_pas[zamena[x]]
    
        print(mas)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно заменить циклом:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
  if zamena[i] > 35:
     zamena[i] = 0
     if i < 4:
        zamena[i + 1] += 1
```

Comment: Можно даже еще лучше: ``for i in range(len(zamena))``. Тогда код не будет жестко привязан к длине списка.